# How to get things off your head in Minecraft Mo' Creatures mod

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I installed the Mo'Creatures mod into Minecraft, then made a fish bowl. After catching a fish I went to put it on top of a bookshelf in my room, but instead of placing it, the bowl just dropped at my feet. When I tried to pick it up my character put it on his head. Now I'm stuck with a fish bowl on my head and I can't find any mention anywhere of how to get it off. There are a number of other animals from the mod that you can put on your head for some effect, but no mention of how to remove them pretty much anywhere.

Comment: I want to say crouching and either clicking or right clicking will do it. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look up at the creature and right click on it when it's on your head to remove it.

[Mo'_Creatures Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mods/Mo%27_Creatures).

Comment: This worked. Also relogging seems to drop whatever is on your head also, which is how I solved the problem before seeing this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Right click with a pick axe.  It works for pets, litter boxes, beds, etc.  I got a litter box stuck on my head...so I really had to get creative and discovered the pick axe.  Works to pick Mo’Creatures items off the floor and your head!

Comment: Are you sure it has to be a pickaxe and it isn't enough to look up? Also: Did you have to look up? If both answers are "yes", then the accepted answer is no longer true.