# How do I get my cat off my head in Mo Creatures

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I was playing in minecraft modded with Mo'Creatures and I have a cat on my head and I can't get it off. I can't find anything about how to get it off and whatever I try it doesn't work. Also I'm using the 1.10.2 version of Mo'Creatures. So how do I get my cat off my head?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107400/how-to-get-things-off-your-head-in-minecraft-mo-creatures-mod) answer you must:

> Look up at the creature and right click on it when it's on your head to remove it.

Full credits go to user user43291 who is sadly, no longer with us.