# How do I remove my kitty from my head and feet in mo' creatures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

While playing with the Mo' Creatures mod in Minecraft, I picked my kitty up on my head and it wouldn't get off. Then I right clicked it while shifting and it got off, but got stuck on my feet. Eventually it will go back on my head. How do I get it off??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get things off your head in Minecraft Mo' Creatures mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107400/how-to-get-things-off-your-head-in-minecraft-mo-creatures-mod)

Comment: My sis jumped in a Twilight Forest portal in struggle of removing the cat from her head. Luckily, the head got free of the cat, though the cat went in backrooms

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

But if you have more than one kitty let the kitty go on your head again then breed the two kitties using cake, there is a chance that the kitty on your head will be the mother and go on the kitty bed and thus go off your head.

To give the kitty on your head the cake, look up and right click the kitty with the cake in your hand. Then to let them breed stay near the other kitty so they CAN breed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, almost killed my poor cat but couldn't bring myself to do it since I named it after my actual cat :( I actually managed to get her off just by going to the title screen, she appeared back in my house, lying down. She unfortunately still sustained the damage but that was something I could deal with.

Answer (score 0):

you can right click it with a lead and it gets off

Answer (score -1):

I have discovered an issue in Minecraft mo' creatures mod so I stepped right in to find help unfortunately I found nothing but hopeless begs for fixing.Anyways when I went back to Minecraft I tried doing what I done with the kitty bed. (Shift to drop and then right click with pickaxe and to put it on my head I right clicked if doesn't work use axe) I understand how desperate you humans must have been so heres the 'recepie' First of all get your axe then try shifting and looking up while hitting the kitty and unfortunately the kitty will pass away but atleast you wont have furry paws in your way. :(   I guess it would be a better idea to not put that kitty on your head or you should just get an ocelote.Plus if you're having a struggle with making the ocelote become you loving cat you sha'll have pacience. It takes a while so you'll just need to give the cat fish untill he becomes a sweet angel :3  Cats are cute! I would sure agree. Don't worry it works I tried. Please rate this with dah stars to get more info and tell me if it wont work.Hopefully the creator will fix the issue I mean it has been a while since that mod was out without partly working. :D   Enjoy the play. Thank you I hope this solved some problems.